# Everyman Neo4J resultset with path

Tags: php, neo4j

I am using Everyman classes to connect to neo4j database

I am trying to create a generic function parseResult  which operates on resultset object(of everyman neo4j)  and return an array of each row attributes. When a normal cypher is executed and its resultset is iterated  I find that 
Each row of result set is of type Node  and I can fetch all its properties by getProperties(). But when I run cypher which involve paths for example to fetch all connected nodes of a user
The cypher is somewhat like this:

```
MATCH(n:User{Uid:$uid}) -[r *1..2]-(m) RETURN m,r
```

in this case some items are of type Row (typically those which contain information about relationship or path) thus I cannot  call  getProperties() on them thus giving me a fatal error .
I want to make a parseResult function as a generic function which can be used to construct an associative array from all the result types.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object inft array, use this:

```
    function object_to_array($object)
{
    if (is_array($object) || is_object($object))
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($object as $key => $value)
        {
            $result[$key] = object_to_array($value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered upgrading to an updated driver for Neo4j ?

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client

Running the same query with neo4j-php-client offers you the availibility of Path objects, also the driver is offering the last 3.0 features from neo4j

```
MATCH p=(n:User {Uid:$uid} ) -[r *1..2]-(m) RETURN p
```

You can the return nodes or relationships from the path :

```
$query = 'MATCH p=(n:User {Uid:$uid} ) -[r *1..2]-(m) RETURN p';
$result = $client->run($query);
foreach ($result->records() as $record) {
  $path = $record->get('p');
  // only nodes
  $nodes = $path->nodes();
  // only rels
  // $rels = $path->relationships();
}
```

More info about paths [here](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client#path)